# Unsupported runtime Python-3.7.2 with heroku-18 stack

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I followed all the steps to deploy my Python / Django application on Heroku, but I get the following error:

```
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python-3.7.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `runtime.txt` contains this, with a capital `P`:

```
Python-3.7.2
```

Change it to be all lowercase as shown on the [supported runtimes page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes), then commit, and deploy again:

```
python-3.7.2
```